# boolean vectors

Tags: java

I am supposed to have 2 constructors and the first of which it asks if `n<=0` it changes n to 1 and it initializes the `Bvector` object to represent the boolean vector with n elements,all set to true.(all in first constructor). How do I return the the size using `getsize` method?

```
public class BVector{
    private int size;
    private boolean[] bVectorData;     

    public BVector( int n ) {       
        if (n<=0){
             n=1;
        }           
        Boolean[] bVectorDara= new Boolean[n];  
        Arrays.fill(bVectorData, Boolean.true);
    }

    public BVector( boolean[] data ) {           
        size = data.length;
        bVectorData = new boolean[size];

        //here copy the elements from array data to array bVectorData
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++ ){
            bVectorData[i] = data[i];
        } 
    }

    public int getSize() {  
    /* returns the size of the boolean vector  */        
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier for us to read.

Comment: in the first constructor you misspelled `bVectorData`. And you can get the size with `bVectorData.length`

Comment: I'd use an IDE if I were you. Real-time 'spellcheck', compile check and auto-complete are your best friends!

Comment: Please tell your teacher that silently changing `n <= 0` to `n = 1` is a bad practice that is not found in good code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an urgent matter that will be of little interest to future visitors.

Comment: @RolandIllig sorry if i worded it wrong but i thinks its asking so the person does not enter negative or zero array elements for n.

Comment: @user3049674: What Roland is trying to say is that, if a user enters -3 as the size of an array, then the part of the program dealing with user inputs should refuse it and display an error message, instead of accepting the input blindly and transforming it blindly to 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

All arrays in Java have a `length` field, containing their size. Yoy should return that from your `getSize()` method. It's quite surprising you don't know that, since you're already using this length field in your second constructor.

Now for your first constructor. It doesn't initialize the instance variable `bVectorData`, of the primitive type `boolean[]`. It creates a local variable `bVectorDara`, of type `java.lang.Boolean[]`. You got it right in the second constructor, so do the same in the first one:

```
bVectorData = new boolean[n];
```

or, to be even clearer:

```
this.bVectorData = new boolean[n];
```

Finally, you need to fill it with `true`, and not with `Boolean.true`, which doesn't even exist.

Comment: thanks so much for your clear answer greatly appreciated. new to programming so i dont understand the concepts well. one last question how would i set all elements to true? i think i should use the not operator ! but can i use it in the object declaration?

Comment: [Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean[],%20boolean%29) can fill your array with true.